# How to access boolean field in content node template?

Tags: 7, theming

I've created a content type (event) that has a boolean field (status). I've created a template in my theme called node--event.tpl.php and I've got just about everything working as intended, but I want part of the template to be conditional based on that boolean.

How can I access that boolean in the template so I can use it in an if/else statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the same way as other fields: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7